# WordPress login form with fancybox

Tags: wp-login-form, validation

I'm using fancybox to show WordPress login form. It works perfectly. However, if the user enters incorrect user name or password, he is redirected to wp-login.php, but I want the validation will take place within the fancybox window.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ajax action or add a custom parameter to your post request and catch it on init action callback.
In that ajax action/init callback you can use wp_signon function to check if the credentials are ok and return proper response. 
I would write some code but I'm on mobile and would take too much.
You can see here an example made with ajax http://fellowtuts.com/wordpress/wordpress-ajax-login-and-register-without-a-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for the example. Can you help me with a simple code? I would like to refresh the page when the user submit the login form.

Comment: `function myCallback(){          if( isset($_POST['mycustomaction'])){             /* process login here using wp_signon */          }      }     add_action('init', 'myCallback');`

Comment: Then simply submit fancybox form to http://yoursiteurl.com/currentDisplayedPage?mycustomaction=1 for example or include a hidden input in your form with name mycustomaction.

Comment: Example form: `<form method="POST" action="<?php echo get_home_url() //here you can use current url or whatever you want ?>">  <input type="hidden" name="mycustomaction" value="1">  <?php wp_nonce_field('nonce_action','nonce_field_name') ?> ..other fields here: username, password, sumbit button..  </form>`